# Trouble with isset function on PHP 5.3.3 Version

Tags: php

I am having trouble with php 5.3.3 `isset` function.This function works on php 5.5.12 version but doesnt work on 5.3.3

Here is My PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['sorgula'])){

    $don = "";

    foreach ($_POST['donem'] as $d) {
        if(end($_POST['donem'])!=$d){
            $don.="'{$d}',";
        }else{
            $don.="'{$d}'";
        }
    }


    $sql = "SELECT id FROM donem WHERE DonemAdi IN({$don})";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $donem = [];

    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $donem[] = $row['id'];
    }


    $rapor->hedefRegresyon($conn,$_POST['indikator'],$_POST['hastane'],$donem,$_POST['unite']);

}else{
    $rapor->hedefRegresyon($conn);
}
```

When I open the page this php codes runs and `$_POST['sorgula']` wont issetted.But when click `sorgula` submit button this will works.

Problem is when the php page opened, normally there is no submit event.So where I am mistake or which php function solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a form to access $_POST array and values from $_POST variable . Please use a form for submission then only $_POST parameter will set . $_POST['sorgula'] variable will be set once you submit a form with method POST . For ex . this is simple form with post method ,

```
<form method="post" class="sample_form"> 
</form>
```

You will need an input field with name sorgula to set $_POST['sorgula'] .

Comment: Thanks but form method is post.And this isnot about form.